# Django Python Email Subject end of text white space not showing

Tags: python, django, email

I have this email to send out with email subject + current date.

```
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = Header("Email Subject for " + str(today.strftime("%d/%m/%y")))
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you
```

When receive the email, the email subject shows Email Subject forDD/mm/yy. Tried add space after "for" as above but it wont show at Gmail.

Is there any way to add a space between for and DD/mm/yyyy?

Comment: What is `Header()`?

Comment: @JohnGordon from email.header import Header. Is just a test I did. If removed, still the white space did not show.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Also as a test to figure out if the problem really is in the code you shared just change your subject completely for a bit. Maybe something like "Test Email Subject" and see if that change gets applied or not.

Comment: Why not use Django's email backend?

Comment: I don't see how this behavior is possible.  I suspect you are overwriting the subject header in some other part of the code that you haven't shown us.  Please show us a COMPLETE example so we can try it for ourselves.

Comment: hi guys, thanks for all the comment and suggestion. yesterday before left for work the issue of the spacing still same, but today after ran the function again. the space is working fine right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a formatted string literal (f-string) for the subject

```
msg['Subject'] = Header(f"Email Subject for {today.strftime('%d/%m/%y')}")
```